# Elemento Span á frente

Tags: html, css, razor, span

Tenho a seguinte coluna de uma tabela:

```
<td style="font-size:10%">
    <p class="list-group-item-text">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Cidade", "Cidade", new { cidadecod = item.cidadecod, contratocod = item.contratocod })" class="list-group-item active" , style="font-size: 15px">
            @item.cidadenome
            <span class="badge" style="font-size: 11px; background-color:@item.statusservidor_stts;">
                @item.statusservidor
            </span>
        </a>
    </p>
 </td>
```

Porém o elemento Span fica atrás da parte em azul, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ele ficasse a frente. O que devo fazer?

Comment: "Ficar na frente", que você diz, é o que, exatamente? A cor do texto?

Comment: Pelo que parece a parte azul está acima do span. Gostaria de coloca-lo acima.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar um `z-index`

```
<td style="font-size:10%">
    <p class="list-group-item-text">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Cidade", "Cidade", new { cidadecod = item.cidadecod, contratocod = item.contratocod })" class="list-group-item active" , style="font-size: 15px">
            @item.cidadenome
            <span class="badge" style="font-size: 11px; background-color:@item.statusservidor_stts;position:fixed;z-index:99999">
                @item.statusservidor
            </span>
        </a>
    </p>
 </td>
```

Comment: Não funcionou desse jeito Alisson.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade a cor da letra dava um efeito que parecia que estava atrás. Alterei a cor da letra para branco com o ***color:white***

```
<span class="badge" style="font-size: 11px; background-color:@item.statusservidor_stts; color:white;">
     @item.statusservidor
</span>
```